# Iterating over a array and getting multiple values

Tags: json, iteration, jq

I have a json file with the following structure:

```
{
    "category": 
    {
        "subcategory": 
            [
                {
                    "id": "1", 
                    "val": "blue",
                    "foo": "blahblah", 
                    "bar": "blahblah"

                },
                {   
                    "id": "2", 
                    "val": "red"
                    "foo": "blahblah", 
                    "bar": "blahblah"
                }
            ]
    }
}
```

I want to transform it to is:

```
{   
    subcategories
    [
        {"id": "1","val": "blue"}
        {"id": "2","val": "red"}
    ]

}
```

The closest I have been able to get it is with

```
cat input.json | jq -c '.[] | \
    {id: .category.subcategory[].id, \
    value: .category.subcategory[].val}' \
    > output.json
```

It doesn't works, but it's close:

1. I don't have the  `subcategories` node.
2. The `id` is always the first value - IOW, `1`

Any help would be awesome!

thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input already has the array you want, so your jq program can be as simple as:

```
{subcategories: .category.subcategory }
```

or, if you only want to retain the "id" and "val" keys:

```
{subcategories: .category.subcategory | map({id,val}) }
```

If (and/or when) you choose to use iteration, make sure you don't have too many iterators.

Comment: There are some other fields in the subcategory that I did not include in the example. That I do not want in the output. In addition to ```id``` and ```value```, there are other fields that I do not want. I guess I can strip it from the output.json.  

But is there a way to filter those out?

Comment: Yes.  I would suggest you update your question so the requirements are clearer.